# Where can I get guidance on a specific OOP style issue?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know that Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask for opinions, so instead I'm wondering where I can ask a question about a specific OOP issue. You can ignore the summary below beyond suggesting where I **can** ask for guidance.

> I apologise for being callow enough to mess around with designing a game.  But I'm messing around with it anyway. And I'm not sure whether this structure makes sense:
>
> ```
> class Character:
>
>     self.name...
>     self.offense_value
>     self.defense_value
>     self.resources_value
>
>     def set.offence(self):
>          self.offence = [algorithm]
>     ...
>
> class Combat(Character):
>
>     ...init class and parent
>     def attack(self, modifier):
>          return self.offence + modifier
>      ...
>
> ...
> ```

Are there any Stack Exchange sites where such a question would be on-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place to ask questions about code *style*, presuming your code is functioning correctly, is [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), Stack Overflow's sister site.